# MVC CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mvc, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

Estou com uma dúvida com relação a passagem de parâmetros entre o MVC.

Estou desenvolvendo a confirmação de e-mail em um projeto. Depois de clicar no link para confirmar enviado por e-mail, o sistema pega por GET, a senha criptografada e "quero alterar o campo 'ativo' no banco de dados".

Início do meu Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('confirma_model');
```

Minha View:

```
$h = $_GET['h'];

    if (!empty($h)) {               
        $this->confirma_model->confirma('$h');
    }else{
        redirect(base_url('/'));
    }
```

Por fim o meu Model:

```
public function confirma($h){
    $this->db->where('md5(id)',$h);
    $dados['ativo'] = '1';
    return $this->db->update('usuario', $dados);
}
```

Muito obrigado!

Comment: Conforme a sugestão do Guilherme Nascimento, tirei as aspas simples da variável, mas ainda não está funcionando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Isso esta errado:**

```
$this->confirma_model->confirma('$h');
```

Aspas simples (apostrofos) não entendem variaveis PHP, basta passar diretamente:

```
$this->confirma_model->confirma($h);
```

Pois atualmente o que o teu `model()` esta recebendo é uma string contendo isto "`$h`" e não o valor de GET.